# why is numpy asmatrix removing commas between elements and forcing my matrix into 1 dimensional?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

When I pass a matrix as an argument to asmatrix, it returns my same matrix but with the column dimension of 1... why is it removing the commas between my elements? It is driving me crazy as I must use asmatrix.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

W = [[-4, -3, -2],
    [6, 0, -1],
    [2, 1, 3]]

print("W", W)
print(np.asmatrix(W))
```

Output:

```
W [[-4, -3, -2], [6, 0, -1], [2, 1, 3]]
Wmatrix [[-4 -3 -2]
 [ 6  0 -1]
 [ 2  1  3]]
```

Comment: When you print the matrix, numpy converts to a "pretty" string format. If you want it to be printed in a way that you can reuse it as code, try `print(repr(np.asmatrix(W)))`.

Comment: `W` is a list of lists, and displays with list rules.  `np.matrix` has different display rules.  But why aren't you using `np.array(W)`? Do spend some time reading basic numpy; it will save you some of this crazy puzzlement.

Answer (score 0):

Your list of lists:

```
In [1]: W = [[-4, -3, -2],
   ...:     [6, 0, -1],
   ...:     [2, 1, 3]]

In [3]: W
Out[3]: [[-4, -3, -2], [6, 0, -1], [2, 1, 3]]
```

That displays with [] and commas.

Objects have a repr and str display method.  `repr` is supposed to be more detailed:

```
In [4]: np.asmatrix(W)
Out[4]: 
matrix([[-4, -3, -2],
        [ 6,  0, -1],
        [ 2,  1,  3]])
```

`numpy` developers chose to make the `str` method "cleaner", omitting to help distinguish it from the list display:

```
In [5]: print(np.asmatrix(W))
[[-4 -3 -2]
 [ 6  0 -1]
 [ 2  1  3]]
```

`asmatrix` is discouraged in the latest numpy versions, instead we should use the basic `ndarray` class:

```
In [6]: np.asarray(W)
Out[6]: 
array([[-4, -3, -2],
       [ 6,  0, -1],
       [ 2,  1,  3]])

In [7]: print(np.asarray(W))
[[-4 -3 -2]
 [ 6  0 -1]
 [ 2  1  3]]
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#printing-arrays